# String value formatting

Tags: coding-style

Sometimes in Strings I see something like this `%1$s` or this `%2$d`. Can somebody explain to me how to read such things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this document http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax the string is basically broken in

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

From your example %1$s,

- `%` means *replace with a parameter*
- `1$` is the position in the parameter array.
- `s` signals that the parameter is a string.

This is taken from Java, but a lot of programming languages use the same syntax for string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

the % stand for the relative argument position, and the "s" or "d" (or others) stands for the type.
This is used to format a string through the printf functions

```
format= 'The %2$s contains %1$04d monkeys';
printf(format, num, location);
```

see the printf docs of the langage you use to get all the details (there is a lot)